# GCC Linker error presumably

Tags: linux, gcc, minix

I am getting the following error:

[image: error]

I am following this tutorial:
http://wiki.minix3.org/en/DevelopersGuide/DriverProgramming

This is my makefile:
[image]

My code is on pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/Jtn2cEsW

http://pastebin.com/YrpKh32m

Edit:
Changing LPADD to LDADD changed the errors to:
[image: error2]

Sorry for the amount of images, I cannot run X11 due to using Virtualbox.

Comment: Vote to close?  It's perfectly clear what the question is here.

Comment: What is the output of "env" on the console? Specifically the values of libsys and libchardriver.

Comment: I'm sorry, my build crashed, couldn't recover it. Found a solution by using the sources in /usr/src/drivers/hello, which compiled fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your makefile, it should be `LDADD`, not `LPADD`

Comment: I am getting an other result now, seems to indicate a missing reference in libchardriver. I updated my initial post to include the errors.

Comment: Now you have bigger problems.  It seems your environment doesn't match the example site and so some other library that should have getprocnr (and others) is not being linked.